# All program windows are grey after updating 13.04

Tags: graphics

I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu 13.04 and have just installed all updates - now when I log in I get grey windows when I open an application. If I maximize the window I can see the contents of it.

Another problem that seems to be related is when I right-click the menu is just a grey box with no content.

Unity does not work at all - I just get a blank screen, however Gnome 3 works to a certain degree (as above).

I have tried adjusting the display settings but since this window cannot be maximised it just displays as a grey box and I cannot see the windows content.

[image: Screenshot of open window]
[image: Screenshot of right mouse click]
[image: Screenshot of Gnome Super menu]

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 (x64), 8GM RAM, ATI 7500HD

Assuming it's a video driver issue but not sure what to do / how to fix without GUI

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this problem fixed by installing the latest beta driver from ati from here http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-3LINBetaDriver.aspx

Extracting the file is simple using unzip in the terminal, run the .run file using sudo. Once the window opens it can be dragged to the top of the screen where if maximises and can be viewed.

Once installed I restarted (had to do the above process twice for some reason) but this put the system back to a usable state.